# Движение блока вдоль границ страницы

Tags: css, css-animation, adaptive

Есть блок, которому я задал анимацию. Нужно адаптировать анимацию блока под разные разрешения устройства. Пробовал задавать *top*, *left* в *%* - не помогает.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

div {
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  max-width: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: green;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не получается адаптировать анимацию блока под разное разрешение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все относительные единицы (*%*, *em* и т.п.) должны отталкиваться от абсолютных значений. У Вас же абсолютные размеры не заданы для `<body>`, и поэтому он имеет минимально возможную высоту, которая равна высоте `<div>` заданной в абсолютных единицах (*px*).

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  height: 75px; width: 75px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  animation: spin 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0%, 100% {
    top: 0; left: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0; left: 100%;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    top: 100%; left: 100%;
    transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
    background-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    top: 100%; left: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -100%);
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```